# Coq proof that factorial N / (factorial k * factorial (N-k)) is integer

Tags: coq, factorial

I could not find the proof that `N choose k` is intergral in the Coq standard library.  What would be a *short self-contained* proof of this lemma?

```
Lemma fact_divides N k: k <= N -> Nat.divide (fact k * fact (N - k)) (fact N).
```

I saw that in [ssreflect.binomial.v](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.binomial.html) they sidestepped the entire problem by defining `choose` recursively, `choose(N,k) = choose(N-1,k) + choose(N-1,k-1)`, and then show that `choose(N,k) * k! * (N-k)! = N!`.

However, it would be nice to have a direct proof of the above, too, without resorting to pascal's triangle.  Many of the "informal" proofs that come up when I search for it here on Stack.* implicitly use algebra steps for rational numbers, and they don't bother showing that it works for strictly `nat` division.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Bubbler's answer below (based on [this math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12121)), the proof is just

`intros. destruct (fact_div_fact_fact k (N - k)) as [d Hd]. 
exists d. rewrite <- Hd. apply f_equal. omega.`

Comment: Is going through Pascal's triangle really not a "direct proof"? Divisibility is defined as `divides q p := (exists w, p = q * w)` and in this case the witness `w` is precisely `choose(n,k)`.

Comment: I was hoping for a proof that did not require identifying the expression as the solution to some recursion equation, which requires some divine insight in general, but rather for a simple proof that only involved algebraic manipulations.  It feels like overkill (although very beautiful) to have to bring in concepts like prime numbers, the fundamental theorem of algebra, or in this case, come up with `choose`, etc.  The informal proofs only require that the product of _k_ consecutive integers are always divisible by  _k!_, (besides the "cheating" rational divisions...)

Comment: That sounds fair. I think all the difficulty of the proof is to be found precisely in that last fact you mention, since, depending on how you formalize it, its statement could almost be the goal you are trying to prove.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: This is not a Coq problem, but a plain mathematical problem.

Comment: @Yves That is true. I was asking how to encode a "plain mathematical problem" in Coq's formalism. Doing this encoding has some hurdles that pencil mathematics usually glosses over, as I mentioned in the above comment. Much math is easy on paper (or latex), but when one tries to encode it into Coq, one runs into problems, in this case about divisibility. There might be someone here in the Coq community who knows of an _elegant_ way to express the specific math problem in Coq's syntax. How that is done can be useful to have seen when one runs into other similar problems. At least that's my guess

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I got interested in this specific problem long ago, and I always thought that using Pascal's triangle was the only way to prove it.  If you know of another proof that is detailed enough that we can reconstruct all steps, I will be interested to help building a formally verified proof.

Comment: @Yves, Bubbler showed how to do that below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unwieldy minus, I'd state it as follows:

```
Theorem fact_div_fact_fact : forall x y, exists e, fact (x + y) = e * (fact x * fact y).
```

I believe you can derive your own lemma from this, combined with facts about `<=` and `-` in the Coq standard library.

And here is the self-contained, not-so-short proof using the [pure algebraic approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12121). You can try running it [here online](https://x80.org/collacoq/ezocipodiq.coq).

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.

(* Let's prove that (n+m)! is divisible by n! * m!. *)

(* fact2 x y = (x+1) * (x+2) * .. * (x+y) *)

Fixpoint fact2 x y := match y with
  | O => 1
  | S y' => (x + y) * fact2 x y'
end.

Lemma fact2_0 : forall x, fact2 0 x = fact x.
Proof.
  induction x.
  - auto.
  - simpl. rewrite IHx. auto. Qed.

Lemma fact_fact2 : forall x y, fact x * fact2 x y = fact (x + y).
Proof.
  induction x.
  - intros. simpl. rewrite fact2_0. ring.
  - induction y.
    + simpl. replace (x + 0) with x by ring. ring.
    + simpl. replace (x + S y) with (S x + y) by ring. rewrite <- IHy. simpl. ring. Qed.

Lemma fact2_left : forall x y, fact2 x (S y) = S x * fact2 (S x) y.
Proof. intros x y. generalize dependent x. induction y.
  - intros. simpl. ring.
  - intros. unfold fact2. fold (fact2 x (S y)). fold (fact2 (S x) y).
    rewrite IHy. ring. Qed.

Lemma fact_div_fact2 : forall x y, exists e, fact2 x y = e * fact y.
Proof. intros x y. generalize dependent x. induction y.
  - intros. simpl. exists 1. auto.
  - induction x.
    + unfold fact2. fold (fact2 0 y). unfold fact. fold (fact y). destruct (IHy 0). rewrite H.
      exists x. ring.
    + unfold fact2. fold (fact2 (S x) y).
      destruct (IHy (S x)). destruct IHx. exists (x0 + x1).
      replace ((S x + S y) * fact2 (S x) y) with (S x * fact2 (S x) y + S y * fact2 (S x) y) by ring.
      rewrite <- fact2_left. rewrite H0. rewrite H.
      replace (S y * (x0 * fact y)) with (x0 * (S y * fact y)) by ring.
      unfold fact. fold (fact y). ring. Qed.

Theorem fact_div_fact_fact : forall x y, exists e, fact (x + y) = e * (fact x * fact y).
Proof. intros x y. destruct (fact_div_fact2 x y). exists x0.
  rewrite <- fact_fact2. rewrite H. ring. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!